# Error Message: undefined reference to 'printHeader()' & undefined reference to 'calculateArea(double&)'

Tags: function, reference, undefined

I wrote this program to calculate the area of a circle and it keeps giving me this error message: "undefined reference to 'printHeader() and undefined reference to 'calculateArea(double&)'"

I cannot figure out what this means! I've looked everywhere including this site but most of the answers are way above my head.

PROGRAM:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Aquire radius value
// Postcondition: print out header and return radius value
double printHeader();

// Precondition: radius has been entered
// Postcondition: calculate and print out area of the circle
void calculateArea(double& radius);

int main()
{
    double area=0.0, radius=0.0;
    printHeader();
    calculateArea(radius);
    return 0;
}

double printHeader(double& radius)
{
    cout << "Program for calculating the area of a circle" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the radius of the circle: ";
    cin >> radius;
    return radius;
}

void calculateArea(double& radius, double area)
{
    double PI=3.14159;
    area = (PI*radius*radius);
    cout << "The area of the circle is: " << area << endl;
}
```

I am using CodeBlocks. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is the compiler telling you that you have declared some functions that have not been defined. If you look at your function prototypes:

```
// Aquire radius value
// Postcondition: print out header and return radius value
double printHeader();

// Precondition: radius has been entered
// Postcondition: calculate and print out area of the circle
void calculateArea(double& radius);
```

Then look at the functions you define later:

```
double printHeader(double& radius) { ... }

void calculateArea(double& radius, double area) { ... }
```

You can see that you are not defining the functions you have prototypes for - the number of parameters is different! The compiler identifies functions based on their scope and parameters. You need to update your forward declarations to include the parameters in your definitions:

```
double printHeader(double& radius);
void calculateArea(double& radius, double area);
```

Another way of describing this is that the function double printHeader() is *not* the same as the function double printHeader(double& radius) - the first takes no parameters and the second requires a double reference.

Comment: Thanks so much! That cleared everything I was confused about right up and now my program works.